# Css animation with one image that contains 4 images

Tags: css, animation

Hello guys i am new to web development and i wanted to learn something today.
This is my image that i want to animate with css.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRUPb.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="picture.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my html code and i want to make that pictures change position (from girl to baby and etc.) withing 2s of it .
And this is what i made with css so far :(

```
img {
    animation-name: slide-show;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes slide-show {
  0% {opacity: 0;,};
  100% {opacity: 1;};

}
```

Comment: hello. what does it mean "that pictures change position"? give more explanation pls

Comment: i suugest you to use lightslider to it very easily.

Comment: The comma after the ; is an error, which will prevent things from working properly.

Comment: What do you mean "change position"? You have one image in your HTML. You can't change the content of an image. To start, you'd need multiple images.

Comment: I mean every time the opacity goes from 1 to 0 when it hits 0 the position of image to change (in my html document only one picture from 4 images is displayed,so when it hits 0 i want image to change similar to slideshow).